# Emacs doesn't output the results into the python shell

Tags: python, shell, emacs

```
#!usr/bin/env python
while True:
    s=raw_input('Enter something: ')
    if s=='quit':
        break
```

This is my program, when I run it, emacs just puts the "Enter something"-dialog in a read-only buffer,
so I can't input any words. Actually it should appear in the python shell!

Answer (score 0):

Try using "C-c !" (or "meta-x pyshell") to start an interactive shell, and then "C-c C-c" (or "meta-x py-execute-buffer") to send it to the interactive shell.

If that doesn't work -- what version/variant of python mode are you using?  "C-c C-v" might tell you if you don't know.